There are some problems in using the Knife4j（swagger enhancement） interface document
I am currently learning and developing a small project. I integrated Knife4j's enhanced interface documentation into the project, but I encountered a problem at the moment. I will explain my problem and the dependency version information of the backend program and the frontend program in the following points.

Problem

  app.c31badf5.js:1 SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.json5parse (app.c31badf5.js:1:364220)
    at r.transformResponse (app.c31badf5.js:1:196382)
    at chunk-vendors.d51cf6f8.js:2:2003275
    at Object.u [as forEach] (chunk-vendors.d51cf6f8.js:2:2005150)
    at e.exports (chunk-vendors.d51cf6f8.js:2:2003248)
    at chunk-vendors.d51cf6f8.js:2:1328322


Java Program


Main dependencies


       <!-- SpringBoot config-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.5</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

     <!-- knife4j-doc -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.xiaoymin</groupId>
                <artifactId>knife4j-openapi3-jakarta-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                <version>${knife4j.doc.version}</version>
            </dependency>


ConfigurerFile

application.yml

 springdoc:
   api-docs:
      path: /v3/api-docs
   swagger-ui:
      enabled: true
      path: /swagger-ui.html
      tags-sorter: alpha
  group-configs:
    - group: 'default'
      display-name: 'Test Model'
      paths-to-match: '/**'
      packages-to-scan: com.prosys.web.controller.tool


WebConfig(implements WebMvcConfigurer)

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    // Add static resource mapping rules     
    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    //Configure the static resource request mapping address of knife4j
    registry.addResourceHandler("/doc.html")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
   }


SecurityConfig

public static final String[] EXCLUDE_INTERFACE_PATHS = {"/login", "/register", "/captchaImage"};
public static final String[] STATIC_SHADER_RESOURCES = {"/", "/*.html", "/**.html", "/**.css", "/**.js", "/profile/**"};
public static final String[] STATIC_RESOURCES_MAPPING_PATH = {"/doc.html", "/swagger-ui.html", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**","/swagger-resources/**", "/webjars/**", "/druid/**"};

protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    return httpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> {
                permitAllUrl.getUrls().forEach(url -> requests.requestMatchers(url).permitAll());
                // For login login registration register verification code captchaImage allow anonymous access
                requests.requestMatchers(EXCLUDE_INTERFACE_PATHS).permitAll()
                        // Static resources, anonymous access
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, STATIC_SHADER_RESOURCES).permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(STATIC_RESOURCES_MAPPING_PATH).permitAll()
                        // All requests except the above require authentication
                        .anyRequest().authenticated();
            })
}


Knife4jDocConfig

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenApi()
    {
       return new OpenAPI().components(new Components()
        // Set the authentication request header
        .addSecuritySchemes("apikey", securityScheme()))
        .addSecurityItem(new SecurityRequirement().addList("apikey"))
        .info(getApiInfo());
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityScheme securityScheme()
    {
       return new SecurityScheme()
        .type(SecurityScheme.Type.APIKEY)
        .name("Authorization")
        .in(SecurityScheme.In.HEADER)
        .scheme("Bearer");
    }
    public Info getApiInfo(){
    new Info().title("interface api")
              .description("This is an interface document for testing the interface")
              .contact("anshink")
              .version("Version:1.0.0");
    }




Web Program

Main dependency: "vue": "3.4.31",

